# paging in gridview

Tags: c#

I had gridview which retriev data from database and filter this gridview when I select ddl .and I allow paging in this gridview .But I noticed that when i selected ddl and the gridview get it,s data and I do through pages number in paging and if I stoped in ex.page number 4.And when I selected ddl again the gridview get it,s data but it stop in page number 4.so how can I make gridview return to first page if i selected ddl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler for the dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged, add this:

```
GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
```